# Some apps won't open anymore

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, facebook, lg-g4, clash-of-clans

I've got a problem on an LG G4 with android 5.0 : Some apps can't be openned anymore. Facebook and and supercell games like 'clash of clans' for instance.

Facebook close each time I try to open it and supercell games are locked on a black screen. That's why I didn't think it was the same issue but both happenned at the same time twice ... it has to be something they have in common...

It happenned a first time and the only way I could unlock it was to factory reset the phone.
It worked then for a few days but here I am with the same problem again and I'm looking for a way to fix this without factory reset each time ...

I don't have any clue... maybe someone here can help ?

Edit :
I tried to uninstall facebook, reboot, reinstall.   still crash at startup :(

Comment: [Android's logs](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info) might give you a clue. Please check, then [edit] your post with your findings. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that it occurs only when developpers options are enabled :/
As a developper, I need to enable those sometimes and the problem appear again.

So now I just disable them when I don't need it and it solve the issue.

If anyone can explain it I would be interrested.

Thx anyway